# laravel, checkbox wont pass form

Tags: laravel, checkbox, input

Why won't checkbox pass into Input? With other input types (text,password,select) it works fine.

form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">

    @foreach ($query as $article)

        <tr>
            <td>{{ $article->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $article->slider }}</td>
            <td><a href="/admin/slider/{{ $article->id }}" class="btn default btn-xs green"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" name="article[]" value="{{ $article->id }}"></td>
        </tr>

        <input name="test" value="tedt" hidden>

    @endforeach

</form>
```

and controller

```
if (Request::isMethod('post'))
{

    dd(Input::get('article'));

}
```

Comment: What does `dd` return when the box is checked and when it is unchecked? If the checkbox is unchecked, it should return `null`. Also, how are you submitting your form? There is no submit button.

Comment: ajax submiting , like i say other input types works FINE. dd return NULL.

Comment: `dd` returns `null` *when*...when the checkbox is checked, unchecked, or both?

Comment: both , nothing happen , like checkbox wasent exist's

Comment: `null` is the correct response when the checkbox is unchecked, so the problem is only with the checked state. Please post your javascript for the ajax submit. Also, try isolating the issue by (1) trying your form with a regular submit button, and (2) removing the [] from the name.